# Calendar control width is too large at initialization of usercontrol

Tags: wpf, calendar, width

I have used calendar control and its display mode is year when my user control is loads then calender width s too large and doesn't appear when width is set .but when is select any month then width is set as it should 
i m not getting what is the issue behind it 
 can anyone help me quickly???

Here is my code and what ever selected month will appear in textbox's text property and on click event of button my calendar control is set to visible

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="HorizontalHorizontalAlignment="Left "Margin="4">
      <Label Content="Month: " HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold" Margin="4"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="SelectedMonthTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Margin="4" LostFocus="SelectedMonthTextBox_LostFocus" SelectionBrush="#FF767879"/>
                <Button Content=".." Height="20" Width="20" Margin="4" Name="button" Click="button_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Calendar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="50,-8" Panel.ZIndex="100"  Name="calendar1" DisplayModeChanged="calendar1_DisplayModeChanged" DisplayDateChanged="calendar1_DisplayDateChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayMode="Year" Style="{StaticResource CalendarStyle}" Focusable="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i took a look your code and from information you provided so far, there is no any change a you describe. I believe that you should check following:

1. What happens in calendar1_DisplayModeChanged
2. How defined your style: StaticResource CalendarStyle

If it possible please post them here. I will try to help as soon as possible :)

Comment: In calendar1_DisplayModeChanged display mode is set to year again and in calendar style nothing is wrong bcoz i have used that style in another control and its works fine in that. and Still i m not getting what is wrong with it...